# Invite Facebook Friends using Django/Python

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-facebook

I need to create an input that looks uses autoSuggest to lookup my friends list and send their 'facebook id' to a Django/Python script. I've completes this without a hitch.

Eg: http://f.cl.ly/items/1J0F3i062n1M0a131T3c/Screen%20Shot%202011-10-20%20at%205.34.35%20PM.png

BUT, what to do with this 'facebook id' array on the other side.

Is it possible to loop though this list to invite these users to use a 'Facebook App'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Canna be done I'm guessing? How does FB assume we get around this if the old school embedded method is looking to be ditched soon. Hmm?

Answer (score 1):

The common way to achieve this kind of behaviour is using the Requests Dialog, easy, client side javascript implementation.  You can read about it in the official facebook docs:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

If you want you can call a callback js function after dialog completes handling user input to record what the user did and send it back (via ajax) to your app.